# My Jupiter/Saturn conjunction calculation with skyfield doesn't match wikipedia

Tags: python, astronomy, skyfield

Using Python-Skyfield to calculate the upcoming conjunction if Jupiter and Saturn.

[Wikipedia Great conjunction times (1800 to 2100)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_conjunction#List_of_great_conjunctions_(1800_to_2100))

**Using Right Ascension:**

- Dec 21,2020 13:22:00 UTC - Wikipedia.
- Dec 21,2020 13:34:33 UTC - My Calculation.

**Using Ecliptic Longitude:**

- Dec 21,2020 18:37:31 UTC - Wikipedia
- Dec 21,2020 18:20:40 UTC - My Calculation.

```py
from skyfield.api import load, tau, pi
from skyfield.almanac import find_discrete

planets = load('de421.bsp')
sun = planets['sun']
earth = planets['earth']
jupiter = planets['jupiter barycenter']
saturn = planets['saturn barycenter']

ts = load.timescale(builtin=True)

def longitude_difference(t):
    e = earth.at(t)
    j = e.observe(jupiter).apparent()
    s = e.observe(saturn).apparent()
    _, lon1, _ = s.ecliptic_latlon()
    _, lon2, _ = j.ecliptic_latlon()
    return (lon1.degrees - lon2.degrees) > 0

def longitude_difference1(t):
    e = earth.at(t)
    j = e.observe(jupiter).apparent()
    s = e.observe(saturn).apparent()

    jRa, _, _ = j.radec()
    sRa, _, _ = s.radec()
    return (sRa._degrees - jRa._degrees) > 0


longitude_difference.rough_period = 300.0
longitude_difference1.rough_period = 300.0

print()
print("Great conjunction in ecliptic longitude:")
t, b = find_discrete(ts.utc(2020), ts.utc(2021), longitude_difference)
for ti in t:
    print(t.utc_jpl())

print()
print("Great conjunction in right ascension:")
t, b = find_discrete(ts.utc(2020), ts.utc(2021), longitude_difference1)
for ti in t:
    print(t.utc_jpl())
```

I'm new to Skyfield so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe Wikipedia is wrong?

Comment: I think you should edit the post to include the wikipedia value as text, for comparison, and a link would also be nice.

Comment: @bad_coder he has the wiki values there as text compared with his

Comment: Thank you all for the follow ups.  I added a link to the wikipedia page.  @Ruli I do not understand your reply stating this was opinion based.  I think I just stated my facts and wanted a clarification as to whether my code was buggy or the reference page was wrong.

Comment: @Ruli pardon me for not noticing that, I must be getting old...I tried to edit the post to make the difference more evident. Someone flagged this post as potentially off-topic, however from a programming POV I think it's a valid question. There's also the issue if this wouldn't be better suited to be posted or migrated to https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/ ... As it might get a better answer/audience there. (Please consider their [help center](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help)). But in any case I'll be following the post. Keep up the good interesting questions.

Comment: @GaryIlijevich perhaps to confirm the validity of the wikipedia values it would be good to ask on astronomy (that's where the subject matter experts are likely to be). If it's a debugging/implementation problem asking here is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your conjection-finding code looks very good, and I suspect its results are far better than those of the Wikipedia — looking at the version history, it’s not clear where their numbers even came from, and unattributed astronomy calculations can’t easily be double-checked without knowing from which ephemeris and software they derived them.

I attach below a slightly improved version of your solver. Here are the tweaks I recommend:

- Pass `epoch='date'` when computing coordinates, since conjunctions and oppositions are traditionally defined according to the celestial sphere of the year in which they happen, not the standard J2000 celestial sphere.
- Before doing any math on the dates, force them into a range of zero to a full circle (360 degrees or 24 hours). Otherwise, you will see the result of the subtraction jump by ±360°/24h whenever one of the right ascensions or longitudes happens to cross 0°/0h and change signs. This will give you “phantom conjunctions” where the planets are not really swapping places but merely switching the sign of the angle they’re returning. (For example: jumping from -69° to 291° is really no motion in the sky at all.)
- Note that both of our scripts should also find when Jupiter and Saturn are across the sky from each other, since the sign of their difference should also flip at that point.
- In case any sources you track down cite the moment of closest approach or the angle between the planets at that moment, I've added it in.

Here’s the output, very close to yours, and again not agreeing well with those old unexplained uncredited Wikipedia numbers:

```
Great conjunction in ecliptic longitude:
['A.D. 2020-Dec-21 18:20:37.5144 UT']

Great conjunction in right ascension:
['A.D. 2020-Dec-21 13:32:04.9486 UT']

Great conjunction at closest approach:
A.D. 2020-Dec-21 18:21:00.2161 UT - 0.1018 degrees
```

And the script:

```
from skyfield.api import load
from skyfield.searchlib import find_discrete, find_minima

planets = load('de421.bsp')
sun = planets['sun']
earth = planets['earth']
jupiter = planets['jupiter barycenter']
saturn = planets['saturn barycenter']

ts = load.timescale(builtin=True)

def longitude_difference(t):
    e = earth.at(t)
    j = e.observe(jupiter).apparent()
    s = e.observe(saturn).apparent()
    _, lon1, _ = s.ecliptic_latlon(epoch='date')
    _, lon2, _ = j.ecliptic_latlon(epoch='date')
    return (lon1.degrees - lon2.degrees) % 360.0 > 180.0

def ra_difference(t):
    e = earth.at(t)
    j = e.observe(jupiter).apparent()
    s = e.observe(saturn).apparent()

    jRa, _, _ = j.radec(epoch='date')
    sRa, _, _ = s.radec(epoch='date')
    return (sRa.hours - jRa.hours) % 24.0 > 12.0

def separation(t):
    e = earth.at(t)
    j = e.observe(jupiter).apparent()
    s = e.observe(saturn).apparent()

    return j.separation_from(s).degrees

longitude_difference.step_days = 30.0
ra_difference.step_days = 30.0
separation.step_days = 30.0

print()
print("Great conjunction in ecliptic longitude:")
t, b = find_discrete(ts.utc(2020), ts.utc(2021), longitude_difference)
for ti in t:
    print(t.utc_jpl())

print()
print("Great conjunction in right ascension:")
t, b = find_discrete(ts.utc(2020), ts.utc(2021), ra_difference)
for ti in t:
    print(t.utc_jpl())

print()
print("Great conjunction at closest approach:")
t, b = find_minima(ts.utc(2020, 6), ts.utc(2021), separation)
for ti, bi in zip(t, b):
    print('{} - {:.4f} degrees'.format(ti.utc_jpl(), bi))
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried my best to avoid my feel of possibility of opinion based answers on this question and looked this up on internet. Found out it is quite hard to find any relevant info that I could trust, so I enumerate these posts (except wikipedia):

[timeanddate](https://www.timeanddate.com/astronomy/planets/great-conjunction) is stating the exact time is *18:20 UTC on December 21*, which is as you have calculated

[winstars](https://winstars.net/en/2020/10/11/jupiter-and-saturn-great-conjunction-2020/) have stated the time when the planets will be at closest angle as *18:25 UTC* and they mention that conjunction will occur at *13:30 UTC*, I am not sure if that is the first time.

Not sure how relevant is [this](http://www.sevenwindsyoga.com/blog/jupiter-saturn-conjunction-2020/), but the conjunction here is stated to be 6.2 degreest at *17:32 GMT*, thus *18:32 UTC*

The most relevant source I was able to find was [in the sky](https://in-the-sky.org/news.php?id=20201221_20_100), where the time was estimated exactly to *13:24 UTC*., based on calculations on data by [Jet Propulsion Laboratory](https://in-the-sky.org/article.php?term=planetary_ephemerides) - source code can be checked [here (c)](https://github.com/dcf21/ephemeris-compute-de430/blob/master/src/ephemCalc/jpl.c).

You can see that mostly not both types of calculation are used, and that the times vary. The reason of that is that in such calculations you need very long floats for best precision. As you are limited by the machine you use, the precision is not perfect. Such as @bad_coder has suggested, you might get better answer in [Astronomy stack exchange](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I just checked and this thread is the only search result for *"Great Conjunction"* (I didn't find any meaningful Jupiter/Saturn combination either). So, at least, it's useful as a signpost by giving a "direct hit", the answer gives a critical analyses of the data with references and the question gives a valid implementation of using a Python library and comparing results.